# How to Troubleshoot Resource Caching Issues in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, browser-cache, cache-control

It'a nextjs project host in aws amplify;
when a request a wasm resource and cache in chorme, chrome could't cache the resource properly.

here is the http cache config

```
Cache-Control:
public, max-age=31536000, immutable
```

the chrome cache behavior is confused that I found:

**1.  when wasm not compressed: size about 50 mb, chrome doesn't cache, but safari and firefox cached**
[image]

[image]

**2.  when wasm is compressed: size about 13 mb, chrome does the right cache behavor**
[image]
[image]

It seems that the size of the cached file has an impact on Chrome's cache policy.but I have no idea
ps: I can't enable compress because I use aws amplify, and cloudfront does not compress the file which size over 10MB

finally, I found a error log when writing to disk, But still don't know the reason
[image]